# Are the Orbital Angular Momentum Operators Linear?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

I'm a bit confused whether or not I can distribute out the operators in the definition of the raising and lowering operators. For example, given:

$$L_{+}|l \space m\rangle = a |l\space m+1\rangle$$
$$L_{-}|l \space m\rangle = b |l\space m-1\rangle$$
where a,b are constants.

Using the definitions of the raising and lowering operators in terms of the x and y orbital angular momentum operators this can be re-expressed as:
$$(L_{x}+iL_{y})|l \space m\rangle = a |l\space m+1\rangle$$
$$(L_{x}-iL_{y})|l \space m\rangle = b |l\space m-1\rangle$$

I'm trying to isolate expressions with only $L_{x}$ or $L_{y}$, so my first impulse is to add and subtract these two equations. Is it valid to distribute out the operators onto the state $|l \space m\rangle$ (I'm not sure if $L_{x}$ and $L_{y}$ are linear)?
$$(L_{x}+iL_{y})|l \space m\rangle+(L_{x}-iL_{y})|l \space m\rangle \overset{?}{=} 2L_{x}|l\space m\rangle = a |l\space m+1\rangle+b |l\space m-1\rangle$$

Comment: Your expressions look right.

Comment: How did you define these operators if not as linear operators on a vector space?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I originally was approaching this from "can I distribute out these operators" and then realised that was the definition of being linear. It only occurred to me afterwards that most operators we're working with in qm are linear